# How to get url list of trash post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, recycle-bin

i have deleted some post in WordPress and they are in now trash i need all post URL list so i can submit in Google removal URL list in webmaster tool. SO how  will i get all the list and write in Robot.txt.

Thanks..

Comment: why downvote down-voter please comment if you downvote

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a great function called [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). The most appropriate use for get_posts is to create an array of posts based on a set of parameters...in your case, the ['trash' status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Trash).

What you do with these posts is then up to you. For example, to echo all of the trashed posts, you could:

```
<?php 
    $posts_array = get_posts( array( 'post_status' => 'trash', ) );

    print_r( $posts_array );
?>
```

Comment: can you please set it with url list